# TNS listner error when trying to connect without tnsnames in c#

Tags: c#, oracle, tnsnames

I'm trying to connect to an oracle DB without having to use TNS names, but it keeps giving this error: {"ORA-12504: TNS:listener was not given the SERVICE_NAME in CONNECT_DATA"}

```
string oradb = "Data Source=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=105.1.12.190)(PORT=1521))(CONNECT_D‌​ATA=(SERVICE_NAME=OMP1)));User ID=user;Password=pass;";

OracleConnection conn = new OracleConnection(oradb); // C#

conn.Open();

OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand();
cmd.Connection = conn;
cmd.CommandText = "SELECT cast(Count(*) as varchar(20)) as trig FROM ZDMSN.TRIGGER_TEST";
```

And here is what is in the 'TNS Names' file:

```
OMP1=
(DESCRIPTION=
   (ADDRESS=
      (PROTOCOL=TCP)
         (HOST=105.1.12.193)
            (PORT=1521)
      )
 (CONNECT_DATA=
    (SID=OMP1)
    )
 )
```

Answer (score 0):

You have conflicting IP addresses (.193 vs. .190). Also, you're connecting with a SID name in the TNS names file, but a SERVICE name in the string. That may or may not work.  Try specifying (SID=OMP1) in your connect string.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following connection string:

```
string cadenaDeConeccion = "User Id=AAA111;Password=BBB222;Data Source=CCC333;Connection Timeout=60;Pooling=false"
```

In your case would look like:

```
string cadenaDeConeccion = "User Id=AAA111;Password=BBB222;Data Source=OMP1;Connection Timeout=60;Pooling=false";
```

For more details you can look at this link:

http://www.systemdeveloper.info/2013/10/oracle-tnsnamesora-network-configuration.html